# Insert Text Between Two Date Variables

Tags: linux, bash, date, unix, operands

I am trying to insert some text between two `date` commands

**Code:**

```
date -u "+%H":00Z --date="1 hours ago" "+%a %b %d" --date="0 days ago"
```

**Error:**

```
date: extra operand ‘+%a %b %d’
    Try 'date --help' for more information.
```

**Expected Output:**

```
11:00Z Fri Oct 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU **`date`** , in 2 steps:

```
date -d @$(date +%s --date="0 days ago") -u "+%H:00Z %a %b %d"  --date="-1 hours ago"
```

Comment: This does not work when I try to modify the `1 hours ago` option. The same hour remains no matter how many times I adjust it, i.e. `-1 hours ago`

Comment: Why do you have two `--date`s? It will only use the last one